# SAP BW delete/create index for latest request

Tags: sap-bw

I'm new to SAP BW and am currently working on optimizing the process chains.
I encountered a chain that loads 3 hours everyday because it deletes/creates indexes for 100 million records every day.

I was wondering if it is possible (since it is a daily chain) to only delete/create indexes for the records loaded in by the latest request?

Comment: Commenting because I don't actually know the answer to your question - but I can tell you that in our system, we only do full rebuilds the indexes weekly, not daily.  Presumably, indexes will be updated when data is inserted even if the full index isn't rebuilt - otherwise the index isn't very useful.

Comment: @BryanCain thank you for your reply, unfortunately this won't work for me. We have to do it daily because there are reports on top of it which are used daily by key users. Otherwise this would be a valid solution.